# Difference between result in a returing a function and printing in Python IDE

Tags: python

given a string, replace every letter with its position in the alphabet. If anything in the text isn't a letter, ignore it and don't return it. a being 1, b being 2, etc. As an example:

```
alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
```

Should return `"20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11"` (As a string.)

```
cc = "The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."
for i in cc:
    if ord(i) >= 97 and ord(i) <= 122:
        s = ord(i)-96,
        print ''.join(map(str, s)),

    elif ord(i)>=65 and ord(i) <= 90:
        ss = ord(i)-64,
        print ''.join(map(str, ss)),
```

Output: `20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11`

The error raised when used inside function:

```
def alphabet_position(text):

    for i in text:
        if ord(i) >= 97 and ord(i) <= 122:
           s= ord(i)-96
           return ''.join(map(str, s)),
        elif ord(i) >= 65 and ord(i) <= 90:
           ss= ord(i)-64
           return ''.join(map(str, ss)),
```

is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/greatergood/Desktop/acsii2.py", line 10, in <module>
    print alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
  File "/Users/greatergood/Desktop/acsii2.py", line 8, in alphabet_position
    return ''.join(map(str, ss)),
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

### Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
map(function, iterable, ...)
```

> Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results. If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel. If one iterable is shorter than another it is assumed to be extended with None items. If function is None, the identity function is assumed; if there are multiple arguments, map() returns a list consisting of tuples containing the corresponding items from all iterables (a kind of transpose operation). The iterable arguments may be a sequence or any iterable object; the result is always a list. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Your arguments `s` and `ss` are `integers` and therefore not `iterable`

Is this what you wanted to achieve?

```
def alphabet_position(text):
    list_of_alphabet = []
    for i in text:
        if ord(i) >= 97 and ord(i) <= 122:
           s = ord(i) - 96
           list_of_alphabet.append(s)
        elif ord(i) >= 65 and ord(i) <= 90:
           ss = ord(i) - 64
           list_of_alphabet.append(ss)

    return list_of_alphabet 

list_of_alphabet = alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
print list_of_alphabet
```

Answer (score 1):

Your non-function variant works by accident.
You have put a comma at the end of the assignments
`s = ord(i)-96,` and `ss = ord(i)-64,`
which makes both `s` and `ss` a tuple
and thus `map` works accidentally.
In your function version you omitted the dangling commas,
hence `map` stops working.

Compare these:

```
s = ord('t') - 96,
print type(s)
```

versus

```
s = ord('t') - 96
print type(s)
```

Note, that your code has a few other problems.

Answer (score 0):

As mkiever says, your first version appears to work because you made `s` and `ss` into tuples. Even though we often write tuples with parentheses, they are actually created by the use of the comma. The parentheses are only needed when the code would be ambiguous without them.

It's not clear why you're doing `map(str, s)` though. `map` is used to apply a function to each item in an iterable, not to a single item. To convert a single integer like `s` to a string you can simply do `str(s)`.

---

You can simplify your test by converting the letters to the same case, rather than handling upper and lower case separately.

```
def letter_ord(c):
    return str(ord(c.upper()) - 64) if c.isalpha() else ''

cc = "The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."
a = [letter_ord(c) for c in cc]
print(' '.join([u for u in a if u]))
```

**output**

```
20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
cc = "The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."
print(' '.join(filter(None, map(lambda c: str(ord(c.upper()) - 64) if c.isalpha() else '', cc))))
```